# Reference number system using PHP

Tags: php, reference, numbers, system

i want to create a page for my clients where they enter a number (reference number) and click submit. They then get transfered to another folder (mini web page) that is their project area.

In other words let's say you are a client. I need a place to show you what I've done and how it looks. Im using my website to do that but I want a place where you can only see your own stuff not other clients' stuff (security issue).

I don't want links, I want a reference number system. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the reference number from the `get string`, so each url can point to something like http://yoursite.com/?ref=AbCdEf or http://yoursite.com/a-page/?this=that&ref=AbCdEf

Then in PHP:

```
<?php
  if($ref = $_GET['ref']){
    // do something with $ref to load the user content
  } else {
    // no ref
  }
?>
```

Comment: awesome thanx. im still studying PHP so I know what to do once im pointed in the right direction. Its just getting the direction that is problematic at times. THnx alot